# jScrollPane - How to get fixed width for track

Tags: php, html, css, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I am using [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) on my website and everything works fine but I want to do the following: Currently the track has a width of 100% (it stretches as much as the content does) but I don't want to make it stretchable as the content, I want it to have a fixed width of for example 400px. 
Is there any chance that can be done? I have tried changing it in style.css but doesn't seem to work :(

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/settings.html

horizontalDragMinWidth = 400;
horizontalDragMaxWidth = 400;

i think this will do the trick

Comment: Well that changes the width of the drag, but I want to change the wholle track. Anyhow, in the meantime I have found the solution:
Find "horizontalTrackWidth" in the jquery file and change it's value to your desired ammount (ex. horizontalTrackWidth = 410;).
Thank you anyway :)